# how to use an array or an ArrayList with indices bigger than Integer_Maximum_Value?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to have a big `ArrayList`, so its index would go beyond `int`, how or what can I use for that?
I already checked that `Vector` does have the same issue, any ideas?

Comment: @azurefrog no it is not that! that one is not solved exactly

Comment: An ArrayList containing 11 million references should be about 42MB, assuming a reference is 4 bytes long.  i viewed this in google.

Comment: If you had a 4 billion entry ArrayList each reference and each object referenced (even a trivial one) would be 24 bytes each, so you would need at least 100 GB of heap.  A better way to store large amount of data is off -heap memory mapped files.  This approach uses almost no heap and can be larger than your main memory making it more practical. Also the overhead per object can be much lower e.g. 4 bytes each.